# Before/after jQuery highlighter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage that shows shorthand code on the left, and its long form on the right. When you hover over code on the left (signified with a space-separated array in the `data-from` attribute), it uses jQuery to highlight corresponding code on the right (signified with a space-separated array in the `data-to` attribute), and vice-versa. It's working great, but it feels very long.

**Script**

```js
function containsAny(haystack, needles) {
    for(needle in needles)
        if (haystack.indexOf(needles[needle]) >= 0)
            return true;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* from to */
    $("[data-from]").each(function(i, e) {
        var $e = $(e),
        froms = $e.data("from").toString().split(/\s+/); // must do toString in case we get an int
        $e.hover(function() {
            $e.addClass("hilighted");
            $("[data-to]").each(function(i2, e2) {
                var $e2 = $(e2),
                tos = $e2.data("to").toString().split(/\s+/);
                if (containsAny(tos, froms))
                    $e2.addClass("hilighted");
            });
        },
        function() {
            $("[data-to]").each(function(i2, e2) {
                $e.removeClass("hilighted");
                var $e2 = $(e2),
                tos = $e2.data("to").toString().split(/\s+/);
                if (containsAny(tos, froms))
                    $e2.removeClass("hilighted");
            });
        });
    });

    /* to from */
    $("[data-to]").each(function(i, e) {
        var $e = $(e),
        tos = $e.data("to").toString().split(/\s+/);
        $e.hover(function() {
            $e.addClass("hilighted");
            $("[data-from]").each(function(i2, e2) {
                var $e2 = $(e2),
                froms = $e2.data("from").toString().split(/\s+/);
                if (containsAny(froms, tos))
                    $e2.addClass("hilighted");
            });
        },
        function() {
            $("[data-from]").each(function(i2, e2) {
                $e.removeClass("hilighted");
                var $e2 = $(e2),
                froms = $e2.data("from").toString().split(/\s+/);
                if (containsAny(froms, tos))
                    $e2.removeClass("hilighted");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**SSCCE HTML**

```html
<H3>Before</H3>
<PRE>
<SPAN DATA-FROM="link-color">*:link</SPAN> {
    <SPAN DATA-FROM="link-color">color: blue;</SPAN>
}

<SPAN DATA-FROM="btn-color">button,
input[type=("button","submit","reset")]</SPAN> {
    <SPAN DATA-FROM="btn-color">color: match(*:link);</SPAN>
}
</PRE>

<H3>After</H3>
<PRE>
<SPAN DATA-TO="link-color">*:link,</SPAN>
<SPAN DATA-TO="btn-color">button,
input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"],
input[type="reset"]</SPAN> {
    <SPAN DATA-TO="link-color btn-color">color: blue;</SPAN>
}
</PRE>
```

<sub>[Full use case](https://BlueHuskyStudios.github.io/MARS)</sub>

How can I make the JavaScript shorter (or at least more OO) without sacrificing functionality? I'm sure it can be shorter or more OO because it's so redundant, but I can't figure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure its either shorter or easier to read but here is one version:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/94oggmga/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var containsAny = function(haystack, needles) {
        for(needle in needles)
            if (haystack.indexOf(needles[needle]) >= 0)
                return true;
    }

    var whiteSpaceRegexp = /\s+/;
    var isFromString = function( isFrom ){
        return isFrom ? "from" : "to";
    };
    var splitData = function( $element, isFrom ){
        return $element.data( isFromString( isFrom )  ).toString().split( whiteSpaceRegexp );
    };

    var createToggleFunction = function( $element, classMethodName, searches, isFrom ){
        return function(  ){
            $element[classMethodName]( "hilighted" );
            $("[data-" + isFromString( isFrom ) + "]").each( 
                function( index, innerElement ) {
                    var $innerElement = $(innerElement);
                    var words = splitData( $innerElement, isFrom );
                    if (containsAny(words, searches ))
                        $innerElement[classMethodName]("hilighted");
                }
            );
        };
    };

    var createHoverFunction = function( isFrom )
    {
        return function( index, element ) {
            var $element = $(element);
            var searches = splitData( $element, isFrom );
            $element.hover(
                createToggleFunction( $element, "addClass", searches, !isFrom ),
                createToggleFunction( $element, "removeClass", searches, !isFrom )
            );
        }
    }

    $("[data-from]").each( createHoverFunction( true ) );
    $("[data-to]").each( createHoverFunction( false ) );
});
```

Or, if you want code golf, then this is much shorter (and definitely very hard to read):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/94oggmga/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){var c=function(h,n){for(x in n)if(h.indexOf(n[x])>=0)return true},w=/\s+/,s=function(f){return f?"from":"to"},p=function(e,f){return e.data(s(f)).toString().split(w)},t=function(e,n,x,f){return function(){e[n]("hilighted" );$("[data-"+s(f)+"]").each(function(_,i){var I=$(i);if (c(p(I,f),x))I[n]("hilighted")})}},H=function(f){return function(_,e) {var E=$(e),s=p(E,f);E.hover(t(E,"addClass",s,!f),t(E,"removeClass",s,!f));}};$("[data-from]").each(H(1));$("[data-to]").each(H(0))});
```

Comment: This is not much of a review. Consider commenting on specific issues or parts you'd change, and why.

Comment: wow this is beautiful! Much more like what I envisioned going in!

Answer (score 2):

Here's your code, and I've pointed out some potential problems:

```
for(needle in needles)
    if (haystack.indexOf(needles[needle]) >= 0)
        return true;
```

While this is possible, I suggest you use `{}` instead. This avoids ambiguity, and future danger, especially when you'll be adding more functionality beyond just a single line.

Additionally, `for-in` runs over prototype properties. If you happen to have a property that is similarly named as a native property in the prototype, you'll be in trouble. To avoid that, check using `hasOwnProperty` before proceeding with the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Probably not better, but there's a shorthand for this: `$(function(){...})`

```
$("[data-from]").each(function(i, e) {
```

I'd probably avoid using attribute selectors. They're known to be slow, depending on the parser implementation. I suggest you stick to classes.

```
froms = $e.data("from").toString().split(/\s+/); // must do toString in case
```

A shorthand to convert stuff to string is to do `'' +` to it. Not so verbose, but it's somewhat elegant and short.

Comment: can you elaborate more on your paragraph about the use of `hasOwnProperty` in `for-in`? Perhaps provide an example?